# Why aren't my photos backing up to i cloud

Tags: icloud, photos

I have a Mac, approx 600 photos have backed up to iCloud, leaving 12,600 which haven't. Boxes for iCloud photo library and iCloud photo sharing have been ticked.  I have 195Gigabytes of unused storage and have given it 24 hours.  How do I get the rest stored

Comment: Can you check the progress in photos app in photos tab at the bottom, like really bottom? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219814/can-i-speed-up-icloud-photo-sync-between-iphone-and-macbook

Comment: With the large number of pictures you have, it will take longer than 24 hours to sync the photos.  Make sure you're connected to power and the Mac doesn't go to sleep at any time.  Also make sure you have a good, strong network connection and that it stays active until this process is done.